# How to perform multiple request in one Play 2 specs2 unit test

Tags: unit-testing, playframework-2.0, specs2

I have a simple web app using Play 2 framework. It has two REST API:

- /write
- /read

I want to implement a functional test for it. I want the test to invoke the `/write` multiple times, then verify the result of `/read`.

But the `route` function returns a `Future`, and I could not find a way to let the **specs2** to wait for my `Future`.

My code looks like:

```
object MySpec extends Specification {

  "/write * 2, then /read" in new WithApplication {
    val write1 = route(app, FakeRequest(GET, '/write')).get
    val write2 = route(app, FakeRequest(GET, '/write')).get
    val read = route(app, FakeRequest(GET, '/read')).get

    // how to chain the requests so the execute one after another, and the specs2 can wait for it?

    status(read) must_==OK
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do something like this?

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.test._
import scala.concurrent.Future

object MySpec extends Specification {

"/write * 2, then /read" in new WithApplication {
   val result = for{
     _ <- route(app, FakeRequest(GET, '/write'))
     _ <- route(app, FakeRequest(GET, '/write'))
     read <- route(app, FakeRequest(GET, '/read'))
   }yield{ read }

   status(result) mustEqual OK
}
```